# Creating a content type in drupal 7 using specific vocabularies

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

I'm trying to make a content type that is a set of vocabulary terms from a given taxonomy. Consider the following taxonomy structure:

```
--Animal Name
----Taxonomic Class
----Number of legs
----Sound it makes
----Fun Fact
```

I want to be able to have a form that looks like this:

```
Animal Name: _____________
Taxonomic Class: _____________
Number of legs: _____________
Sound it makes: _____________
Fun fact: _____________
```

The problem I am having is that when I create my content type, I can only have a term reference for an entire taxonomy; not a single term.

Is there a way to link specific fields in a content type to individual terms within a taxonomy or is there a module that will help accomplish this?

Comment: What's your content type name? I don't get quite well what you are trying to accomplish. Term references ALWAYS refer single terms and not vocabularies (they are not called taxonomies).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get quite well what you are trying to accomplish. BUT, to create an Animal content type.

You could create a vocabulary called Taxonomic Class. Then set up a content type with a term reference field to The Taxonomic Class, an integer field for the number of legs. A textfield field for the sound it makes and a textarea for the fun fact. The name of the node will be the animal name.

That will do the form you need.

Answer (score 1):

Never used it before, but this module is being used by over 2,300 sites.  Check it out: http://drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree